# when is paredit-close-round's combined nature useful?

Tags: emacs, paredit

paredit-close-round (which is usually bound to close paren) combines two things:

1. `C-M-- C-M-u`
2. delete some spaces

The doc for the function has this simple example:

```
(a b |c   )
->
(a b c)|
```

I see why `C-M-- C-M-u` is useful; it's useful to use before `C-x C-e`, and I also see why a command for deleting those spaces may be useful, but I don't see why there is a command that combines the two. There must be a usage scenario I am missing which would explain why the space cleaning feature is added particularly to `paredit-close-round` but not to its forward counterpart `paredit-backward-up`.

Comment: Just fyi... paredit-forward-up is bound to C-M-n, you don't need to use C-M-u with a prefix to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`paredit-close-paren` sort of implies you're done editing that sexp, so any whitespace that's left at the end should be deleted. Plus, it's bound to an "editing" key (close-paren), so it's ok that it changes buffer content.

`paredit-forward-up` (or backward-up with a negative prefix) is a movement command, so it shouldn't change buffer content.

Here's a use-case: (point is at the `|`)

```
(let ((hi t))|
  (forward-char 1)
  )
```

1. If you're done editing that `let` statement, then that newline (after the `forward-char`) should be deleted, so you hit `)` which moves you out of the `let` and cleans it up nice.
2. If you're not done editing that `let`, but you want to move out of it for now, then you may actually want to *keep* that newline (it makes it easier to move to the right place and it helps you remember there's unfinished business), so you use `C-M-n` instead, which moves you out of the `let` without editing anything.